# Ionic 2 chaining promises

Tags: ionic2

How do I send multiple requests to a server with ionic 2 ?

I have three tables in a `sqlite` dB that works offline. I would like to synchronize this with server when there is active internet connection.
I proceed like this :

1. Send the data of the first table - if it is successful, it will return the inserted `IDs` from the server. Accordingly, I  update the local data with the new `ID` and update the second table relation with first table `ID`.
2. then I proceed to send data for the second table and I do the some operation like the first table then proceed for the third table.

   ```
           synchData() {
       let result = [];
       this.userDao.get('TOKEN').then(tkn => {
             this.itendao.getAll().then(itins => {

                   for (let i of itins) {
                         let event = {
                               Token: '',
                               Itin: {
                                     itin: Object(),
                                     relevs: {
                                           relev: Object(),
                                           obs: []
                                     }
                               }
                         }
                         event.Token = tkn;
                         event.Itin.itin = i;
                         this.relevedao.geItenReleve(i.IdItin).then(rlvs => {

                               for (let r of rlvs) {
                                     event.Itin.relevs.relev=r;
                                     this.especesobsDao.getReleveObs(r.CodRel).then(obs => {
                                           event.Itin.relevs.obs.push(obs);
                                     });
                               }
                         });
                         result.push(event);
                   }
                   console.log(result);
             });
       });
   ```

How to do that with ionic 2 ?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please share code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use implement by using flatMap and subscribe :

```
     this.userDao.get('TOKEN').flatMap(tkn => {
        return this.itendao.getAll()
     })
     .flatMap(itins => {
        for (let i of itins) {
            let event = {
                        Token: '',
                        Itin: {
                          itin: Object(),
                          relevs: {
                          relev: Object(),
                          obs: []
                          }
                        }
            }
        event.Token = tkn;
        event.Itin.itin = i;
        }
        return this.relevedao.geItenReleve(i.IdItin)
      })
      .subscribe(rlvs => {
          for (let r of rlvs) {
            event.Itin.relevs.relev = r;
            this.especesobsDao.getReleveObs(r.CodRel).then(obs => {
                event.Itin.relevs.obs.push(obs);
           });
       }
    })
```